# Create PHP array for web services with array_push

Tags: php, xml, web-services

I'm not really sure about title but i will try explain what I want.
I have web service and i need to pass parameter in to it. My script reading the file and values from every single row adding into array and finally  post it to web service.

```
$create = array
(
    'Invoice' => array 
        (
            'TMP' => 
                array (

                        'Number' => $array[0]['customer_number'],
                        'Id' => $array[0]['id'],
                        'Code' => $array[0]['code'],
                        'Qty' => $array[0]['qty']        
                      )

        )

);

$action = $client->create($create);
```

To create this for every single line in a file I need to repeat (create new array with `$array[1] $array[2]...` and pass it ) but to call web service every time i think not best idea.

Is it possible to generate array with multiple parameters and pass it in one go?

something like this:

```
$create = array();
 foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
      array_push($create, array
        (
            'Invoice' => array 
                (
                    'TMP' => 
                        array (

                                'Number' => $value['customer_number'],
                                'Id' => $value['id'],
                                'Code' => $value['code'],
                                'Qty' => $value['qty']        
                              )

                )

        )

    );
}
```

But something wrong with new array structure.

Comment: And what is wrong? We should guess or __you__ can explain?

Comment: `But something wrong with new array structure.`it's not a useful statement. Please clarify what is wrong happening?

Comment: @AlivetoDie when i pass it to web service then error message appears... basicaly telling that structure incorrect. `Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to YVDomDocument::fromMixed() must be an instance of DOMElement, instance of YVDomDocument given, called in`

Comment: but it works with first example. Is it possible to do that with foreeach?

Comment: may be because your web service not supporting multiple elements. Its not script issue.

Comment: @B.Desai but array structure is correct?